# Counting surjections: what's wrong about the following reasoning?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to count the number of surjections $[m]\to [n]$ for $m\geq n$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. According to Wikipedia, the number of such maps is $n! S(m,n)$ for the Stirling number of the second kind $S(m,n)$, which is certainly not my result. I'm wondering, then, what is wrong about the following reasoning.

If $f$ is one of these surjections, then there is at least one subset $S\subseteq \textrm{dom}\ f =[m]$ such that $f|_S$ is a bijection. My idea, consequently, is to  count surjections as follows. For any $S\in \binom{[m]}{n}$ there are $n!$ bijections $f_S:S\to [n]$. Moreover, for any fixed $S$ and bijection $f_S$, the remaining elements in $[m]-S$ can be freely mapped without altering the surjective nature of a map $F: [m]\to[n]$ such that $F|_S=f_S$. There are $n^{m-n}$ such maps. As a result, there are $\binom{m}{n}n!n^{m-n}$ surjections.

However this is false. What is my reasoning missing?

Comment: Any given surjection might admit several subsets which map bijectively to the target.  How do you handle these redundancies in your count?

Comment: For problems like these, a good plan of attack is to take some small values $m,n$ for which the proposed formula is false (easy to find here) and then track the argument through line by line to see where it breaks down for the particular example.  Here take $m=2$, $n=1$ for example.

Comment: @lulu I thought I was taking these redundancies into account by constructing a surjections as the "combination" of a bijection from $n$ elements and any map on the remaining elements.

Comment: Nope.  Take a look at the example I mentioned.  Obviously there is only one surjection from $[2]$ to $[1]$ (indeed, there is only one function).  And you count that one map twice.

Comment: " as the "combination" of a bijection from n elements and any map on the remaining elements" but there are more than one combination to the same result.  Example:  Suppose our domain is $\{1,2,3\}$ and our codomain is $\{a,b\}$.  Take the surjection $1\to a, 2\to b, 3\to a$.  Now that is "combination" of an injection $\{1,2\}\to \{a,b\}$ of $1\to a, 2\to b$ and the function $\{3\}\to \{a,b\}$ of $3\to b$.  ***BUT*** is is also a combination of an injection $\{1,3\}\to \{a,b\}$ ($1\to a;3\to b$) and function $\{2\}\to \{a,b\}$ ($2 \to b$).

Comment: I think the official answer *is* actually trying to do what you did but take the proper procedures to reduce the overcounting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of construction is, to start with an arbitrary $n$-element subset of $[m]$, build an arbitrary bijection on this set with $[n]$, then freely map the remaining points. I certainly buy that every surjective map can be built this way, hence the number of surjective maps is at most $\binom{m}{n}n!n^{m-n}$.

But, you are over-counting!  As you suggested in your proof, $S$ is not (necessarily) unique. Indeed, $S$ is only unique if $n = m$. Otherwise, there will be multiple subsets $S$ of $[m]$ such that $f|_S$ is a bijection. This means that multiple different choices of our subset $S$ will lead to the same map, but your counting method counts each construction separately. Therefore, you are strictly over-counting when $m < n$.

To illustrate this point, consider the map $f : [3] \to [2]$ defined by $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 2$ and $f(3) = 2$. We could construct this map either by considering the subset $S_1 = \{1, 2\}$, choosing the identity map as our bijection, and freely mapping $f(3)$ to $2$. Or, we could construct it via $S_2 = \{1, 3\}$, making our bijection map $1 \mapsto 1$ and $3 \mapsto 2$, then freely choosing $2 \mapsto 2$. Your counting argument counts both of these separately, but both yield the same surjection.

Comment: I actually ended up calculating myself this number! Using inclusion-exclusion principle I could conclude that the number of surjections $[m]\to [n]$ is given by $\sum^n_{j=0} \binom{n}{j}(-1)^j(n-j)^m$. I'm always surprised by how powerful this method is.